# Правильная реализация привязки событий к itemView из списка

Tags: java, android, listview, service

Есть список музыки с телефона, и в этом списке нужно показать проигрывания музыки.

Само проигрывание происходит в сервисе, и в listView нужно показать какая песня играет, и так же показать сам ползунок проигрывания.
В принципе я подозреваю как это реализовать, но не думаю что это совсем правильно. В общем, вопрос таков: Как правильно реализовать привязку данных из Service к данным ItemView из ListView/RecyclerView ?

Comment: Для наглядости https://pp.vk.me/c633722/v633722400/17c8d/tZsVnhNvwvk.jpg

Comment: И второй скрин https://pp.vk.me/c633722/v633722400/17c95/8tRl_oVOQME.jpg